# D3 charts interactive repository and learning center

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 charts, Have worked on highcharts before, But for me, this looks like big guy. feeling difficult to understand. So I want to know, if there is d3 chart repositories on web (just like jquery plugin repository), So that I can download the matching chart and can do some minor changes, and that should work. Since I have only 2 months time to finish the project having full d3 charts. So I have planned like this.

Please guys, need to support and suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NVD3 is a decent library for a variety of basic, ready-to-go charts:

http://nvd3.org/

If you need more specific, in depth examples, check out Mike Bostock's Blocks page:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock